# Gsub function in R

Tags: r, gsub

I have the following sentence:

```
trying <- 'Happy CNY to You <-U+2661> Abundance BLESSING to you and your family! <-U+2661> happy and blessed year ahead! '
```

I want to remove all the `<.....>` entities in this sentence. I used the following function:

```
comment = gsub(pattern = "<.*>", replacement = "", x= trying)
```

However, I was returned with:

```
"Happy CNY to You happy and blessed year ahead! "
```

May I know how I can edit the code such that I'll have the following:

```
"Happy CNY to You Abundance BLESSING to you and your family! happy and blessed year ahead! "
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because regex matching is greedy. You can put a `?` in the expression.

```
comment = gsub(pattern = "<.*?>", replacement = "", x= trying)
```